# How can I solve so my transparent gif does not show a black background in Xamarin forms iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am adding a GIF to my project that works well but if i add a transparent gif with no background into my xamarin forms project with my following code below i get a black background.

It is something here i must change `background: #000000;`but i am not sure what to write in there instead to make it transparent.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GifView_iOS))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
  public class GifView_iOS : IGif
  {
    public string Get()
    {
        return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
    }
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IGif
{
    string Get();
}
```

Control:

```
public class Gif : WebView
{
    public string GifSource
    {
        set
        {
            string imgSource = value; 
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            html.Html = String.Format
                (@"<html><body style='background: #000000;'><img src='{0}' /></body></html>",
                 imgSource);
            SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
        }
    }
}
```

How I use it in xaml:

```
<controls:Gif GifSource = "myGif.gif"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 5, 0.25, 0.25" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  />
```

Comment: You are explicitly setting the background to be black: `style='background: #000000;'`

Comment: You might need to change the hex colour code to rgba(0,0,0,0) which includes an alpha channel set to `0`, e.g. it becomes invisible, but I haven't tried this.

Comment: When I changed it to this: `@"<html><body style='background: rgba(0,0,0,0);'><img src='{0}' /></body></html>"`I get a white background instead

Comment: If i do this: `@"<html><body style='background: #ffffff; opacity: .4;' ><img src='{0}' /></body></html>"` and put the opacity to .4 the gif gets low opacity but not the whitebackground. if i put it to .0 then i only see a white background

Comment: Have you try without style? Without setting a background in the html part?

Comment: yeah i tried that but then nothing showed at all

Answer (score 0):

Try giving "transparent" itself as background style.

```
<html><body style='background: transparent;'><img src='{0}' /></body></html>
```

Comment: Tried it! But I get a white background behind the GIF.

Comment: Could you share the gif file. So that I can look into it... @UnoDosCode

Comment: Yea sure! I am currently testing with this one: http://giphy.com/gifs/lol-spongebob-5GCKZHxhmXBWU

Comment: You also recieve a white background when you test it right?

Comment: yep.. But its not background it seems by default its white in iOS, Not so sure... If you wish, share your XF project so that I'll configure and check my Mac...